# Why concurrent reading instead of mean in titration?

Tags: titration

While doing titration we take concurrent reading like.

Reading..........Concurrent reading

1. 3.6
2. 3.4=====> 3.4
3. 3.4

Why don't we take the mean value as we do in physics?

Comment: When you say "physics", what exactly do you mean? Many things follow a standard distribution, readings from a voltmeter e.g. usually don't, operator bias doesn't, ... Without a rigorous error estimation, just taking a mean can be a bad choice.

Comment: Could you attempt to add more detail (explain more clearly what you mean, for instance in your example)?

Answer (score 4):

We usually refer to the *[median](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StatisticalMedian.html)* rather than the mean. In the case shown, when you have two readings that are identical and one that's different, the median is the reading with two values (here, 3.4) rather than averaging all three (here, that would be 3.5 to two significant figures).

The trade-off goes like this: when we are sure that all the data are normally distributed in one population, the mean represents the best estimate of the true average value. But in many types of experiments, including titration, we have to guard against being influenced by a sample where we went wrong with the procedure or there was some contamination in the sample we couldn't see beforehand. The median is less sensitive to such abnormality in the experiment, and the resulting non-normality in the statistics, than the mean. This is in exchange for being a less optimal estimate if we could be sure everything were perfect/normal.

Comment: Nice answer, especially considering that you had to infer that from the question. (I honestly had no clue.)

Answer (score 1):

First! A buret reading should be to the estimated 0.01 mL, the first Insignificant figure not to the gradations of 0.1 mL. One titration is one data point. If you want to check your overall precision the procedure is to run complete replicate samples on the one sample or [even on simultaneous replicate samples to check on the sampling technique]. Since only 2 or 3 replicates are usually run, when readings are to the first insignificant figure a simple average is sufficient and the range is a good approximation to the error. In your case the buret should have been read to 3.61 3.43 3.46 [making up last digit] average is ~3.50 error is ~0.15; ~5% relative error quite unacceptable in titrations. To apply correct statistics more data points are needed. Data such as this simply means that your technique needs serious improvement. Once you have the technique down pat such data could be meaningful and there is something going on with your sample. This is why I strongly advise that standard solutions be standardized by the user. First to ensure the source is competent and second to ensure one's technique and equipment are up to par on a known reaction.

I worked as an applications chemist for a instrument manufacturer and was dismayed on finding out how many of the labs I visited were working with uncalibrated or improperly calibrated instruments.

Conclusion: run 2-3 complete replicates. Read the buret to the first estimated digit. If the data has no variation or if the variation is in the significant digit or relative error is greater than 1%, something is wrong.